# Windows desktop Outlook Add in on Send does not work

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am having problems with Desktop Outlook Add in on Windows, it does not work at all and it is blocking my appointment to be created. On the web it works perfectly and I investigated versions that support the onSend feature on this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets

I am using Microsoft 365 subscription with version 2008 (build 13127.21348) which support Requirement sets 1.9 (from my understanding) and therefore it should support the onSend functionality, however it doesn't. Is there anything I need to allow or modify in order to work on Windows Desktop?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The on-send feature was officially released in requirement set 1.8, not 1.9. However, the feature's support matrix is a superset of the requirement set's. So, you need to make sure the Exchange server supports this feature as well. From your posting it is not clear which Exchange server version is used. Is it Exchange Online?

Anyway, I'd suggest testing a sample add-in first to make sure the issue is not brought by your manifest or JS code. Read more about the `On-Send` event in the [On-send feature for Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows) article in MSDN.

The [Outlook-Add-in-On-Send](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send) sample project is a good way to start. If it doesn't work, I'd suggest using Fiddler to see what is going on under the hood and whether any web calls are made to your web app.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will do that!

Comment: I had the same issue on my road. Sometimes it is hard to realize what is wrong. It is not obvious if we compare to COM add-ins.